# LongPressHold Switch Not Evaluating to Ended/Failed (Drop & Drop Freeze)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView that I add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to. When a cell is held, it triggers a switch that evaluates the gesture state:

```
switch state { 
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        //Takes a snapshot of the cell, shows image and hides cell
        print("User held cell.")
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        //Runs when cell-snapshot is dragged 
        print("LocationInView is: \(location)")
    default:
        //Runs when the user "lets go" of the cell
        print("User let go.")
 }
```

During testing, cells freeze if dragged above or below the table AND let go of. If dragged back over the table and let go of, it's okay.

The table does not occupy the whole screen and the cell stops at the edge of the table if a user tries to drag it out of the table's bounds. When you let go while 'out of bounds' the cell freezes on the edge permanently.

[image]

I can simply hide the cell IF the switch tells me the gesture finished but the problem is that the default never fires. If the users lifts their finger after leaving the table, the switch never evaluates to default.

Now UIGestureRecognizerState has "cancelled", "ended", and "failed" states so why aren't they triggering the default? I have print statements to show a normal finger lift:

[image]

And a finger lift outside of the table area:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question wasn't apparent from the code but was in the image. The cell is being dragged "out of bounds", or off the table/to its edge. Once there, it cannot pass an indexValue to be evaluated!

This is the solution because most tableView drag/drop code will first check for nil, including my own:

```
    if indexPath != nil {
        switch state {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            ...
```

The part that's tricky is how to handle the situation now that you can't evaluate the recognizer state... did it end/fail/cancel? If I were to start over I'd try to make add the recognizer to the full screen view so that I could always monitor the gestureRecognizer state no matter where the user's finger goes.